# MySQL Delete Query With RLIKE Expression

Tags: mysql, regex, expression

I am trying to run a query to delete duplicates based on an expression. The expression that I am trying to use is this.

`category-23023` or `category-link-2398` or `category-link-url-58693435`

Basically, I need an expression that checks to see if the string preceding the `-` dash symbol contains an alphabet followed by a dash and finally a number. This is what I have tried last which doesn't work.

```
delete
from core_url_rewrite using core_url_rewrite,
    core_url_rewrite e1
where core_url_rewrite.url_rewrite_id > e1.url_rewrite_id
    and core_url_rewrite.target_path = e1.target_path 
    and core_url_rewrite.target_path RLIKE '^[a-z]+\\-[0-9]$';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, should work.

```
delete
from core_url_rewrite using core_url_rewrite,
    core_url_rewrite e1
where core_url_rewrite.url_rewrite_id > e1.url_rewrite_id
    and core_url_rewrite.target_path = e1.target_path 
    and core_url_rewrite.target_path RLIKE '^[a-z]+\\-*.*\\-[0-9]+$';
```

Comment: regexp and rlike are synonyms

Comment: Thanks. I just tried that but i get `Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp`

Comment: I was able to get if fixed based off the answer you gave with just a bit of tweaking. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was able to get this working by altering Riad's code just a bit.

```
delete
from core_url_rewrite using core_url_rewrite,
    core_url_rewrite e1
where core_url_rewrite.url_rewrite_id > e1.url_rewrite_id
    and core_url_rewrite.target_path = e1.target_path 
    and core_url_rewrite.target_path RLIKE '[a-z]+\\-[0-9]+$';
```

Comment: `SELECT  'sdf-js00-009' RLIKE  '[a-z]+\\-[0-9]+$';` should match the string ...but this one doesn't with the solution you provided.